# Django "Similar Objects" Based on Similar Tag Sets

Tags: jquery, python, django, postgresql

Lets say you have 1k objects, each of which have 10-50 tags.

For any given object, there must be a list of objects that have keywords in common with it from most to least.

Yet within Django parameters I know of no way to query in such a way.

**Does such a thing exist in django or should I write an algorithm outside of django's constraints?**

---

```
class Product(models.Model):

    product_id = models.IntegerField(
        unique=True,
    )

    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
        blank = True,
        null = True,   
    )

    meta_description = models.TextField(
        max_length = 160,
        blank = True,
        null = True,    
    )


    title = models.CharField(
        max_length = 160,
        blank = True,
        null = True,
    )


    description = models.TextField(
        blank = True,
        null = True,    
    )

    first_subject_heading = models.CharField(
        max_length = 160,
        blank = True,
        null = True,
    )

    description_main = models.TextField(
        blank = True,
        null = True,    
    )

    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, 
        decimal_places=2,
        blank = True,
        null = True,        
    )

    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    tags = TaggableManager(
        blank = True,
    )

    category = models.ManyToManyField(
        'ProductCategory',
        blank = True,
    )

    license_selection_model = models.IntegerField(
        default = 1,
        blank = True,
        null = True, 
    )

    minipic = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='minipics/',
        blank = True,
        null = True, 
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('store.views.product', args=[self.slug])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and not self.slug:
            #Only set the slug when the object is created.
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) #Or whatever you want the slug to use
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%i, %s"%(self.product_id, self.title)
```

This is using postgres and the taggit extension (taggit's "similars" option has an error)

Comment: Please add the corresponding models.

Comment: I'm looking to match on tags...model added.

Comment: Does `some_object.tags.similar_objects()` work?

Comment: Will try again, but got an error last time I tried. Will post results

Comment: Surprise surprise, it did! I wonder what changed. Let me check for accuracy...

Comment: What was the error you got earlier?

Comment: It had something to do with key error - was a few days ago. But yes, this is accurate. A little slow, but I can deal with that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) provides a [`TaggableManager`](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager) to help in working with their API. **It provides a [`similar_objects()`](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.similar_objects) method** which returns a list of objects tagged similarly to a particular object in decreasing order of similarity.

From the [docs:](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.similar_objects)

> `similar_objects()`
>   Returns a `list` (not a lazy `QuerySet`) of other
>   objects tagged similarly to this one, ordered with most similar first.
>   Each object in the list is decorated with a `similar_tags` attribute,
>   the number of tags it shares with this object.

```
# returns list of objects tagged similarly
some_object.tags.similar_objects()
```

Comment: `some_object.tags.similar_objects() ` return's another models. how we can get just instances?